# How can I make this Time assertion match perfectly with either Time, Date, or DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, minitest

I have an assertion in a test that looks like this:

```
assert_equals object.sent_at, Time.now
```

When I run this test, I keep getting an error that looks like this

`--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Fri, 04 Mar 2016 18:57:47 UTC +00:00
+Fri, 04 Mar 2016`

I've tried a few combinations to make this test pass.

My actual code updates the `sent_at` value with a `Time.now` but its not quite in the perfect format. It is close but not enough to pass. How can I make this test pass.

Here are some combinations I've tried in my assertions:

`Time.now.utc`
`Date.today`
`Time.now`

and a lot of `to_time` , `to_datetime` etc. How can I make the test pass?

Comment: It seems `object.sent_at` is returning a `Date`, no time is shown for your 'actual' result. So I don't think testing against a `Time` object would be the right approach. If you did `assert_equals object.sent_at.to_db, Date.today` does that help? I'm tempted to say `assert_equals object.sent_at, Date.today` should be good enough, but it appears you may have tried that already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Old but still valid... The output shows that the comparison is against UTC which would be Time.current

At this time you would probably use:

```
assert_in_delta object.sent_at, Time.current, 1
```

To tolerate <1 second difference

Answer (score 6):

Using Time#to_i isn't the best solution. If the task you are running takes more than a second the comparison would fail. Even if your task is fast enough, this comparison would fail:

```
time = Time.now # 2018-04-18 3:00:00.990
# after 20ms
assert_equal Time.now.to_i, time.to_i # Fails
```

Time.now would be `2018-04-18 3:00:01.010` and to_i would give you `2018-04-18 3:00:01` and time was `2018-04-18 3:00:00.990` and to_i: `2018-04-18 3:00:00`. So the assert fails.
So, sometimes the test would pass and others would fail, depending on when (in miliseconds) it starts.

The better solution is to freeze the Time. You could use a gem like [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) or write your own code, like (using MiniTest):

```
current_time = Time.now
# You need Mocha gem to use #stubs
Time.stubs(:now).returns(current_time)
```

You can also use a block, so that after the block the clock is back to normal

```
# For this you don't need Mocha
Time.stub :now, current_time do   # stub goes away once the block is done
  assert your_task
end
```

Comment: Yup. Just got that same issue! Thanks for timecop. It's been a lifesaver. One thing, is "stubs" part of TIme? I was having issues. I ended up using `.freeze` instead

Comment: #stubs is actually from Mocha (I'll fix the answer), which is awesome btw.
Minitest has a method called #stub, which is the second option in my answer

Comment: Thank you :D I used Timecop and it was a lifesaver! Simple to use and works flawlessly ;)

Comment: In the second example, `current_time` may as well be replaced with `Time.now` so it would work anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is easiest to use [Time#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html#method-i-to_i) to compare the time in seconds.

`assert_equals object.sent_at.to_i, Time.now.to_i # seconds`

Comment: This was what I needed! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, Gorodscy's answer is more complete. Definitely a good idea to use Timecop or a stub to ensure `Time.now` stays constant for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timecop` gem: https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

```
def test
  Timecop.freeze do # Freeze current time
    Time.now # some value
    ...
    Time.now # The same value as previous
  end
end
```